# Missing values from JSON decoding in Python

Tags: python, json, list, decode

I'm actually going crazy from trying to understand how to decode a JSON log received through a REST call.

This is the code i have:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=(a, b))
parsed = json.loads(r.content)
for request in parsed['logs']:
    for z in request["request"]["input"]:
        print(z)
```

If i execute:

```
print request["request"]["input"]
```

The ouput is the following:

```
{text:sample string}
{text:fake string}
..
```

While if I execute the code above, the only thing i get on screen is "text".

I'm really looking to understand what I'm doing wrong, as I wasted the last hour trying all the solutions I could find online.

I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Thank you guys in advance for your time

Comment: you're printing the `key` of each dictionary not the actual value hence `text` only printing because thats the name of the `key`

Comment: `request["request"]["input"]` is a dictionary so you're essentially iterating and printing its keys (which happen to be `text`). If you replace `print(z)` with `print(request["request"]["input"][z])` you'll be printing its values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=(a, b))
parsed = json.loads(r.content)
for request in parsed['logs']:
  for key, val in request["request"]["input"].iteritems():
    print(key, val)
```

Comment: You might as well use `r.json()` whilst your at it too. It saves importing the `json` library.

Comment: That was perfect thanks! I could not find any reference to this way of solving this problem. Again, thanks a lot!